# Would the White House maintain and preserve a voice recording of the Presidential telephone calls?

Tags: united-states, president, donald-trump

Please note: that a similar question was asked two years ago , however none of the answers (including one entered today) actually answered the specific question of whether an actual voice recording is made and preserved. Please see my comments to Jonathan as to specifically why the other answers DO NOT address the question.

The significance of the question has to do with the accuracy and credibility of evidence that may be used in an impeachment proceeding. For example, if the TELECON of the Trump-Zalenskyy were to be entered as evidence, one might expect a prudent lawyer to attempt to impeach that document based on the Caution notation at the bottom of the page.

So I ask the question again:

The "transcript" of the President's call here carries the notation: "A Memorandum of a Telephone Conversation.· (TELCON) is not a verbatim transcript of a discussion. The text in this document records the notes and recollections of Situation Room Duty Officers and-NSC policy staff assigned to listen and memorialize the conversation in written form as the conversation takes place."

Would there be an **actual voice recording** of presidential calls, that would serve as a the basis of verbatim transcript?

And if not, any reports on why not?

Comment: @JonathanReez - the question you cite, did not adequately answer this question. The answer provided by Ashan Kahn cited DLT's tweets (tweets from DJT tend to lack credibility), the others - including Fizz's posted yesterday does not address **actual  voice recording**, but rather that listeners produce a transcription. What I am asking is if an audio recording or audio file is made ( seemingly a fundamental step in the process of production of a digitally searchable transcription) - and if that record or file is produced  --- is it preserved?

Comment: There isn't a good answer there yet but the **question** is essentially the same.

Comment: @JonathanReez, agreed - however, recent events have elevated the significance of the question - which is why I've asked if anyone has a better (or more recent) answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't how StackExchange works. However you may offer a bounty on the original question to attract attention to it.

Comment: @JonathanReez I'm not trying to be argumentative, but I took to heart the advice that SE gives, specifically: " _If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question._" So that is what I did, or at least attempted to do. But thanks for the additional advice.